# Is an affine formal scheme quasi-compact?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, soft-question, schemes, affine-schemes

It is well known that an affine scheme $X=\mathrm{Spec}(A)$ is quasi compact. In analogy, what can we say about an affine formal scheme $\mathrm{Spf}(A)$ (here $A$ should be an adic ring and $\mathrm{Spf}(A)$ is defined to be the set of all open primes in $A$ with respect to the adic topology)? Is it also quasi-compact? If the answer is no, what additional conditions can guarantee the quasi-compactness?

Comment: Let $I$ be an ideal of definition. Then the underlying topological spaces of $Spf(A)$ and $Spec(A/I)$  are homeomorphic to each other.

Comment: So you mean it is still quasicompact right？

Comment: Yes. This follows from what I said.